# Divinity: Original Sin Enhanced Edition crashes - Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: games, radeon, crash, 21.10

I've got a problem with the game. I'm probably using the latest version (v2.0.119.430.CH). The game crashes upon loading level or mid-game. So far the main menu works OK.

SPECS: AMD Athlon Silver 3050e with Radeon Vega 3, 4GB DDR4. (maybe I need more RAM?)

There's a discussion here with a possible solution but I'm new to Linux and understand little from it, so I'd require some step-by-step instructions with explanation: https://www.gog.com/forum/divinity_series/linux_original_sin_ee_crash_on_startup/page1

Thank you for your time.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: You may need to look at the log files in `/var/log` to see if there’s something a little more specific to explain the crash 

Comment: I only know how to use the Logs application, here's the paste: https://pastebin.com/DfcUs4N1 . Please tell me what files should I copy from /var/log to paste here, if the one above is not enough.